# Unity Messaging System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Read Bellow.

Bullet Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {
    public float bulletLifeTime = 5;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //If bullet life time exceeds 5 seconds destroy bullet
        bulletLifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (bulletLifeTime < 0)
        {
            CleanupBullet();
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        NotifyHitTarget(collision.gameObject);
        CleanupBullet();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        NotifyHitTarget(collider.gameObject);
        CleanupBullet();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleanup the bullet and remove it from the scene
    /// </summary>
    public void CleanupBullet()
    {
        //Destroy bullet
        GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notiffy a given game object that it has been hit by this bullet
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameObject">The game object that has been hit by this bullet</param>
    public void NotifyHitTarget(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        //Need to use the Unity Messaging System here to send a message to GoalPickup to notify it that it has been hit
        Debug.Log("Collision");
    }
}
```

Pickup Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public abstract class Pickup : MonoBehaviour {

    /// <summary>
    /// Unity will send this message when a collider has entered the pickup trigger zone
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collider">The collider that entered the trigger zone</param>
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null) 
        { //check if the collider has a rigid body attached
            PlayerController player = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();

            if (player != null) 
            { //the rigid body that collided with this pickup was a player
                onPlayerCollect(player);
                GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notify the player has collected this pickup
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="player">The player that collected the pickup</param>
    protected abstract void onPlayerCollect(PlayerController player);
}
```

GoalPickup Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GoalPickup : Pickup
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GameController.SpawnGoal();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    protected override void onPlayerCollect(PlayerController player)
    {
        Collect();
    }

    void Collect()
    {
        GameController.PlayerCollectGoal();
    }
}
```

I have been trying to use the unity messaging system to notify my GoalPickup that is has been hit by my Bullet. I have to want to complete this script within my Bullet script using my public void NotifyHitTarget(GameObject gameObject) method. The GoalPickup script inherits from the Pickup script so I have attached both scripts along with the bullet script. any help is appreciated, Thanks for your time. I have tried many different ways, researched Google for the a solution extensively and still can't seem to find a way to notify the GoalPickup's that they have been hit using the unity messaging system please help me and sorry for the long scripts I was unsure which parts of the scripts would be needed.
Thanks -Joz

Comment: Also goalPickup must inherit MonoBehavior for it to work. So if you have something like this public class GoalPickup : Pickup{ }, change it to public class GoalPickup : MonoBehaviour {}. I usually dont use inheritance in Unity because Unity does its stuff some ways that aren't C# standard. Many people have reported problems while using inheritance. Its hard to explain here but you should be able to do this without any inheritance at all.

Comment: Once you get your simple code working, then you can go ahead and start messing with inheritance.

Comment: @Programmer My Pickup inherits from MonoBehaviour does that mean GoalPickup does as well also i need GoalPickup to inherit from my Pickup.

Comment: I really don't know but the code I provided below should work if you do it the way I did. Just like I said before, I don't know how Unity implemented this but I have seen multiple people on Unity forum having problems with it. I also read somewhere that the class you are calling must inherit MonoBehaviour *directly* before GetComponent<EnemyScript> can be used. What I am suggesting is that you do it the way below, if it works, then you know you can't do it with inheritance even though the base inherits MonoBehaviour. I only use inheritance in C++ but not in Unity C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To notify another object when the bullet collides with it, you need to create another script and attach it to that object. Lets use an example, For example lets say that is a GameObject called Enemy on the Scene. Create a script called EnemyScript and attach it to that object. Make a simple public function called bulletHitMe and inside that function you can do what ever you want when the bullet collides with this enemy.

The code below is a working example,

In you EnemyScript:

```
public class EnemyScript: MonoBehaviour {

public void bulletHitMe(){
  Debug.Log("I was hit by the bullet");
  //Do other stuff here
 }
}
```

In your BulletScript attached to the Bullet

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
    {

        //Get the referene of the EnemyScript attached to the GameObject that the bullet collided with.
        EnemyScript hitEnemy = collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyScript> ();

        //Call the function
        hitEnemy.bulletHitMe();
        CleanupBullet();
    }
```

You can also do this using the Unity built in sendMessage like this

`collision.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("bulletHitMe",SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver)`;

inside the  `void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision){}`

**EDIT**:

You are getting  NullReferenceException because the object is colliding with other objects that does not have the EneyScript attached to it. Use if statement to determine if the object the bullet is colliding with is an enemy. You can check the enemy by name but my recommended way is to tag all the enemies then call the script function only if the tag is an enemy. For example, lets just say that your enemy is tagged ad "jozza710",  put this code inside the oncoll

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision){
//Check if this is an enemy before calling script
      if (collision.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("jozza710")) {
        //then you can call the script function attached to the enemy
         EnemyScript hitEnemy = collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyScript> ();

                //Call the function
                hitEnemy.bulletHitMe();
          } 
        CleanupBullet();
        }
```